# UNITY 3D - sinking object issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

My object sinks below the surface even though gravity is set to 0 and I have made no other changes. What might be causing this and how do I fix it?
[components used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwJuH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the wording of your question, it seems as if your object is simply stuck within your surface, as opposed to falling through.

If this is the case, then there could possibly be a logic error within your code with the initialisation of your object's `transform.position` component. Unity uses the center of GameObjects as the reference point for all `transform.position` values, so if you've set your object's `transform.position.y` to 0, then simply add half of your object's height to `transform.position.y`.